# R: Impulse Response Function

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to visualize an impulse response function in R. Let us consider following code:

```
library(vars)
Canada <- Canada * 1000
var <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "both")
plot(irf(var, impulse = "rw", response = "U", boot = T, cumulative = FALSE,     n.ahead = 20))
plot(irf(var, impulse = "rw", response = "U", boot = T, cumulative = TRUE,     n.ahead = 20))
```

Produces:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

**Question:** Is it anyhow possible to show the % shock/change of U instead of the absolute value? It seems that most papers with IRF are using a % scale.

(I could not find an R example time series that would create better data)

Answer (score 1):

The forecast error variance decomposition is based upon the orthogonalised impulse response coefficient matrices `Ψh` and allow the user to analyse the contribution of variable `j` to the h-step forecast error variance of variable k. If the orthogonalised impulse reponses are divided by the variance of the forecast error the resultant is a percentage figure.

Answer (score 0):

The solution may be transforming the raw data into percentage changes for the time horizon you're looking for and then running the analysis.